# php require from folder one level down

Tags: php

Why does this not work?

```
@require("../scripts/glossar/src/start_replace.php");
```

It is a sample from the **index.php** of a open source glossar script.

I tried to include this index.php file, but nothing is shown.

```
<?php include('../scripts/glossar/index.php');?>
```

If I open the index.php directly it works fine, if i let the code with the standard line, like it is after downlading the script:

```
@require("src/start_replace.php");
```

I also tried to include the index.php with that unchanged line (script out of the box).

My site structure is like this:

- httpdocs
- .. / index.html
- .. / glossar.php - include?
- scripts
- .. / glossar
- .. / ../ index.php - require?
- .. / .. /.. / src

**Can require go one level down or not?**

Comment: The `@` won't help you figure anything out. And include paths are relative to the current working directory, which is the dirname of the invocation script. Just use `DOCUMENT_ROOT`-relative paths instead.

Comment: In which script does this not work?

Comment: Its a german glossary script with the name "vionlink".

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your server's error log? If it's giving you a file-not-found error then your path might be wrong. I often give an absolute path from the website root just in case I later move something around.